# extracting VPs/NPs connected with conjunctions using Tregex for Stanford Parser

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp

I want to split the trees based on conjunctions and commas. For example, when I have `VP and VP` or `NP and NP` or `VP, VP` or `NP,NP`, I would like to extract each VP or NP separately. I have the following code:

```
 List<Tree> subtrees = constituent.subTreeList();

                for (int i = 0; i < subtrees.size(); i++) {
                    String s = "@VP $+ CC $+ @VP";
                    TregexPattern p = TregexPattern.compile(s);
                    TregexMatcher m = p.matcher(subtrees.get(i));
                    while (m.find()) {
                        m.getMatch().pennPrint();
                        Tree foundTree = m.getMatch();
                        System.out.println(m.getMatch());
                    }
                }
```

But it doesn't work for the following text. What is wrong with my code?

```
(VP (VP (VB manage) (NP (NP (DT the) (JJ entire) (NN life) (NN cycle)) (PP (IN of) (NP (PRP$ your) (NNS APIs))))) (CC and) (VP (VB expose) (NP (PRP$ your) (NNS APIs)) (PP (TO to) (NP (JJ third-party) (NNS developers)))))
```

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn’t work”? What output or exception are you getting? What is your expected output? Also, why are you compiling your pattern for every subtree?

Comment: @dantiston I repeat it for all the subtrees, because I expect to get ALL VP or NPs conjuncted with a conjunction. The problem is that the code doesn't find any match. Is something wrong with the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that chained Tregex relations (following the tradition of tgrep and tgrep2) have a special non-associative semantics: `A r1 B r2 C [r3 D]` means `A r1 B` and `A r2 C` and `A r3 D`. (This usually makes sense for the core use case of `A < B < C` meaning an A node with B and C children. To get another grouping, you need to use parentheses. In particular, the pattern you want here is `"@VP $+ (CC $+ @VP)"`.

This is documented in the [Tregex Javadoc](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html) under the list of relations, but I realize that this is an easy mistake to make, especially since the semantics is quite non-standard relative to typical mathematical or programming language expressions.

There are then some other improvements to be made, as noted by @dantiston. You should compile the pattern just once outside loops, as for a regular regex. Also, you're much better off just letting Tregex iterate over the nodes of a tree rather than constructing a full list of all subtrees. Here's some good example code:

```
Tree t2 = Tree.valueOf("(VP (VP (VB manage) (NP (NP (DT the) (JJ entire) (NN life) (NN cycle)) (PP (IN of) (NP (PRP$ your) (NNS APIs))))) (CC and) (VP (VB expose) (NP (PRP$ your) (NNS APIs)) (PP (TO to) (NP (JJ third-party) (NNS developers)))))");
List<Tree> trees = Collections.singletonList(t2);

String s = "@VP $+ (@CONJP|CC $+ @VP)";
TregexPattern p = TregexPattern.compile(s);
for (Tree t : trees) {
  TregexMatcher m = p.matcher(t);
  while (m.findNextMatchingNode()) {
    Tree foundTree = m.getMatch();
    System.out.println(foundTree);
  }
}
```